# How to change default in ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: customization, custom-distributions, customizer

Now these days I am working on a project in which I have to **customize the ubuntu** as per the requirement. I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS i386 architecture edition for the customization.

I want to change the defaults for my customize OS like :

1. I want to change the default theme.
2. I want to change the default icon set
3. Unity Top bar color and position.

Lightdm directory is not present in `/usr/lib` to change the  defaults  , so tell me from where i can change it ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use  [unity-tweak-tool](https://github.com/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool) or [ubuntu-tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) and then copy the modified files if you want to create a custom version of ubuntu